# Best Practise to expose service in kubernetes using Calico

Tags: networking, kubernetes, nat, calico

Having set up a kubernetes cluster with calico for the one-ip-per-pod networking, I'm wondering what the best practise is to expose services to the outside world.

IMHO I got two options here, BGP'ing the internal pod IP's (172...) to an edge router/firewall (vyos in my case) and do an SNAT on the firewall / router. But then I'd need one public IP per pod to expose.

Pro: less public IP's need to be used
Con: Pod changes need updated firwall rules?!

Or 2nd: Taking the provided public network and hand it over to calico as an IP pool to be used for the pods. 
Con: lots of public IP's wasted for internal services which won't get exposed to the internet

Hope someone could enlighten me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calico doesn't provide any special way to expose services in Kubernetes.  You should use standard Kubernetes services, node ports and the like to expose your services.  In the future, there's a possibility that Calico will offer some of the features that kube-proxy currently does for Kubernetes (such as exposing service IPs) but right now, Calico fits in at the low-level networking API layer only.  Calico's real strength in the Kubernetes integration is the ability to define network security policy using the new Kubernetes NetworkPolicy API.

Source: I'm one of Calico's core developers.

Comment: Hi Fasaxc, first, thanks for your answer and for your work on calico, I think it's a great project. 
My question originated from what I saw on a video from the CoreOS Fest '15 where  Spike Curtis said that you could connect Calico directly to your Infrastructure to advertise routes outside your datacenter to let people connect straight in. This made me wonder how it would be done correctly. Check out the [Video at 13:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44wOK9ObAzk&feature=youtu.be&t=13m05s)

Comment: If you were running OpenStack or raw Docker, say, then you'd only have one set of IPs, which would be exposed.  The difference is Kubernetes has its service infrastructure, which sits in front of the pod IPs.  We haven't "taken over" that feature from Kubernetes and "Calico-ised" it (yet), but we may do in the future.  Right now, if you want the k8s experience, with service IPs etc then you need to run kube-proxy in front of Calico.

Comment: @Fasaxc        why is it that i cant use ipBlock when using calico and kubernetes 1.7?

Comment: I found this article [here](https://www.projectcalico.org/enable-ipv6-on-kubernetes-with-project-calico/), it seems to suggest a setup using calico to expose kubernetes resources (perhaps not services) with calico. Would be great to have ipv6 support.

Answer (score 0):

Calico is not responsible for the k8s service IP management or for translating service ip to container (workload endpoint) It allocates IP addressses to the newly created pods and does necessary system config changes to implement the calico policies